# Eclipse's Tomcat gives a 404 while the WAR file works-previous solutions don't work

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, server

So when I'm running my project through Eclipse's "Run on server" the 'server' doesn't work (when trying the URI http://localhost:8080/simpleapp/ there is an automated 404 Tomcat's webpage), but when compiling and deploying the WAR file through Tomcat's app manager it works fine (the exact same URI gives the response I expected).

How can I systematically solve the issue? 
It's important for me to solve it since debugging is a living hell this way right now (can't do a step-by-step debugging,every time that I want to check something I have to re-deploy my project :(  ).

I've looked for hours for a solution so I've tried lots of different settings, and the proposed solutions don't work here.
Specifically,when changing the server's configuration in Eclipse to 'use tomcat installation', it doesnt work through eclipse (and the WAR file cannot be undeployed and doesn't work either!),switch location doesn't work either...

More details which are optional but might help:

I have another project where the server through Eclipse does function, I've just used a different Maven archetype this time. When Eclipse's server 'worked' I used jersey-quick start-web app but this time I had to use (org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-heroku-webapp (An archetype which contains a quick start Jersey-based web application project capable to run on Heroku)) and added dynamic web module through project facets and as I said now the Eclipse server doesn't work (oh and I've tried to delete the server and reset the configuration too, but no luck).

Comment: When you access `http://localhost:8080/simpleapp/` are you certain that anything _should_ be coming up?  Check your `web.xml` to see what is going on.  Most likely, Eclipse was launching Tomcat with a welcome page.

Comment: Yes I am sure,the @GET method should be called. As I said, when I compile and deploy it throught Tomcat's manager (not in eclipse) it works fine. I will check that xml file now.

Comment: By the way,it's not a 'nothing' response,but a full 404 page response. I've looked at the web.xml file and can't see anything special. It is very similar to the web.xml files of the project where Eclipse's Tomcat works.

Comment: I take back what I said earlier.  It looks like Eclipse is not deploying the WAR at all.  Can you verify that Tomcat even is running when you launch?

Comment: read the bottom paragraph of the question if you are not sure (I've written it before your first comment was written). I have another project that is running within Eclipse when I hit run on server,so I don't think it'sabout what is running and what is not...

Answer (score 0):

Try to deploy your WAR using "Add and Remove" from the Servers view instead of using "Run on Server". If the WAR doesn't appear check the Project Facets and ensure that Dynamic Web module is enabled.

Comment: Marco I think that this is how you control the Tomcat running on  Eclipse. I've added the project which appears under Add and remove. As I said in the question it is enabled (see the bottom paragraph).